# ¿Cómo hacer que un procedimiento almacenado guarde los datos en las tablas correspondiente?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

no entiendo porque me pasa que aunque a nivel de sintaxis mi procedimiento almacenado este "bien" a la hora de correrlo ma sale "o rows afected" y no se inserta los datos que quiero guardar en las columnas señaladas ¿por qué pasa eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás utilizando un `UPDATE` en lugar de utilizar un `INSERT`, `UPDATE` solamente actualiza los registros existentes. Lo otro es que por favor coloques en tu pregunta el código como texto y no como imagen. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, y disculpa por lo del código es que soy nuevo por aquí,xd

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que estas usando `UPDATE` en lugar de utilizar `INSERT`, algo asi deberia funcionarte:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertarClientes
@id int,
@Nombre nvarchar(100),
@fechaIng date,
@estado int
AS
BEGIN
insert into Cliente (id,nombre,fechaIng,estado)
values (@id,@Nombre,@fechaIng,@estado)
END
GO

exec insertarClientes 5,'Jose Ramirez','2018-01-26',8;
```

Ojala sea lo que buscas. Saludos.